# Facebook login button disappears if I refresh the page in IE 9

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook login button disappears whenever I refresh the page in Internet Explorer 9. All other browsers are OK. IE only shows the button first time any refresh make it disappear.

I am using facebook connect with folowing code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({appId: '193048084076885', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

            };
            (function() {
                var e = document.createElement('script');

                e.src = document.location.protocol +
                '//connect.facebook.net/tr_TR/all.js';
                e.async = true;
                document.getElementById("fb-root").appendChild(e);
            }());
    </script>
```

and fb button

```
 <fb:login-button v="2" size="medium" length="long"  perms="email, user_about_me,  user_birthday, user_education_history, user_hometown, user_interests, user_location, user_photos"></fb:login-button>
```

Do you know any workaround?Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution, put following to above the head section.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

Comment: Yeah, IE has strange issues with xmlns till today.